# Find and replace particular string in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table in the database where it contains some of the user name. When I copy the database files from one machine to other machine, I need to manually update this table. The table contains the username in the following format

```
<domain name>\Username
```

the domain mostly the local machine name (the user exists within the system). What I am trying to write a simple SQL Query to find a pattern (machine name) and replace with a new one.

I am not so proficient with SQL queries. Can you share a sample snippet? I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: did you miss something in the format (in the question) ? What is `domain` in this context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_that_contains_users
SET field_user = replace( field_user, 'OLDDOMAIN\', 'NEWDOMAIN\')
```

is that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this statement:

```
UPDATE your_table SET machine_name = REPLACE(machine_name, machine_name, 'Your New Value')
```